# How can I duplicate rows of data "x" times where x is variable in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence, flatten, google-query-language

I have these two columns in Google sheet:

| Region | Traffic |
| --- | --- |
| Japan | Online |
| Korea | Offline |
| Ghana | Mix |

I would like a way to use an automatic formula that creates this:

| Region | Traffic |
| --- | --- |
| Japan | Online |
| Japan | Offline |
| Japan | Mix |
| Korea | Online |
| Korea | Offline |
| Korea | Mix |
| Ghana | Online |
| Ghana | Offline |
| Ghana | Mix |

Any idea on how to do this in google sheets? :)

Comment: As you clearly mention you are working with Google Sheets, I've removed the Excel related tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(QUERY(
 FILTER({A2:A&"♠"&B2:B&"♣"}, A2:A<>""),,9^9), D1), "♣")), "♠")))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")&"♦"&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""))), "♦"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Would you mind explaining what ♣ is in this context?

Comment: @kmac thats just a unique symbol. you can use any you wish: ♦♣♠♥☻♫♂♀♪...

Comment: Quick question, for the second solution "=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")&"♦"&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""))), "♦"))"

Is it possible to repeat it x amount of times? Sort of saying =rept(,5) repeat it 5 times

Comment: @kmac sure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhXA1.png